# How should I edit a patch checkout when removing lines?

Tags: git, bash, patch

I have a file `bar.txt` in which I removed 3 lines and did not stage anything yet. I want to restore one of the removed lines via `git checkout -p`.

Example/Bash output:

```
$ git checkout -p foo/bar.txt
diff --git a/bin/custom/foo/bar.txt b/bin/custom/foo/bar.txt
index 35483b7..e945cae 100644
--- a/bin/custom/foo/bar.txt
+++ b/bin/custom/foo/bar.txt
@@ -1097,9 +1097,6 @@ mond.desc.refinements   = Foo
 mond.desc.removeAttribute                    = Foo
 mond.desc.resultsForStore                    = Foo
 mond.no.results                              = Foo
-mond.page.CO.class.name                      = Foo
-mond.page.CO.parent.name                     = Foo
-mond.page.brands.parent.name                 = Foo
 mond.page.cmscontent.datetime                = Foo
 mond.page.currentPage                        = Foo
 mond.page.firstPage                          = Foo
```

I've tried things like:

```
@@ -1097,9 +1097,8 @@ mond.desc.refinements   = Foo
 mond.desc.removeAttribute                    = Foo
 mond.desc.resultsForStore                    = Foo
 mond.no.results                              = Foo
-mond.page.CO.class.name                      = Foo
 mond.page.CO.parent.name                     = Foo
 mond.page.brands.parent.name                 = Foo
 mond.page.cmscontent.datetime                = Foo
 mond.page.currentPage                        = Foo
 mond.page.firstPage                          = Foo
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd probably go about this in the other direction. It's less mind twisting to `git add -p` the changes you *want*, commit them, and then `git checkout .` to clear the other stuff. If you don't actually want to commit yet, just `git reset HEAD^` to undo the commit we just made, leaving the kept changes in your workspace.

But that's not what you asked, and not nearly as fun, so...

---

This is confusing in the way double negatives aren't not confusing, but you can manage it if you bend your brain right.

Let's say we have the file `numbers`, containing:

```
one
two
three
four
```

We delete `two` and `three`, so `git diff` looks like:

```
diff --git a/numbers b/numbers
index f384549..a9c7698 100644
--- a/numbers
+++ b/numbers
@@ -1,4 +1,2 @@
 one
-two
-three
 four
```

Now we run `git checkout -p numbers`. Notice the prompt asks if you want to *discard* the hunk that subtracts `two` and `three`. If you say `y`, it discards the subtraction, leaving you with a complete file including all four numbers.

```
 one
-two
-three
 four
Discard this hunk from worktree [y,n,q,a,d,/,e,?]?
```

So now we'll edit the hunk to create *the hunk we want to discard*. That means if we actually want to delete only `two`, we want to discard the change that deleted `three`. Counter to intuition, that means you edit the hunk by *deleting `-two`*.

```
@@ -1,4 +1,2 @@
 one
-three
 four
```

This discards the removal of `three`, and does not discard the removal of `two`, leaving us with the diff:

```
diff --git a/numbers b/numbers
index f384549..ceb5927 100644
--- a/numbers
+++ b/numbers
@@ -1,4 +1,3 @@
 one
-two
 three
 four
```

So to summarize, delete the lines from the hunk that you *still want deleted*. Leave the subtraction lines you want to discard. Your edited hunk will contain subtractions (to be discarded) for the lines you're *keeping* and will not contain the lines you still want to remove.

Comment: What you say actually makes sense but I'm not being able to replicate it. Maybe this is due to me using Cygwin instead of a "real" UNIX system. Will try to get my hands on one and try it.

Comment: I read and appreciate your explanation and here's a summary I can use **TL;DR:** When editing the patch, change it as if you were *applying* all changes you want to keep (remove `-` lines, change `+` lines to a space) and leave the the changes (`-` and `+` lines) that you want to discard.